# Azure Data Discovery and Classification

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

With the recent preview release of 'Data discovery & classification' for Azure SQL databases, has anybody found where this data is stored and if it can be queried directly from the Azure database?  I know for on-premise databases if you right click on a database and choose 'Tasks - Classify Data...' anything you enter into that interface is stored as extended properties on the 'table/column'.  However, after entering the same data via the interface in the Azure portal, there are no extended property values that I can find in my Azure SQL database.  I would really like to be able to query this classification data directly so I can incorporate other metadata about the column such as data type, sample value, collation etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Azure SQL DB, this metadata is stored in new attributes that have been introduced into the SQL Engine to support tagging column sensitivity, which are currently not exposed. We plan to expose them via REST/Powershell/T-SQL as the feature continues rolling out.

Please follow our announcements and the online feature documentation for updates.

Thanks,

Gilad (MSFT)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Just out of curiosity, is there a reason why these attributes are stored in different places for on-premise vs Azure?  Also, is there any timeline for when these attributes will be available via T-SQL?

Comment: Changes to the SQL Engine (e.g. new metadata attributes, the ability to audit the sensitivity of data returned by queries) cannot be introduced for downlevel SQL versions, which is why for existing on-premises SQL Server versions we are utilizing Extended Events. In terms of timeline, I cannot provide a specific time frame at this point.